# How to remove the 'vector iterators incompatible' error?

Tags: c++, vector

I've inherited responsibility for several thousand lines of code, that in many places generates the 'vector iterators incompatible' error in debug mode.  I'm currently using Visual Studio Professional 2013 Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4.

Example of code that produces this error:

```
 int SqlHandler::VerifyColumnsInFilters (std::vector<TERMS*>*WhereFields,const int Idx, 
                                     std::vector<TABLES *>*Tables)
{
    int Status = 0; 
    for (std::vector<TERMS *>::iterator witer = WhereFields [Idx].begin (); 
    witer != WhereFields [Idx].end (); ++witer) 
    {
```

I've tried changing the above code to:

```
std::vector<TERMS *>& whereVector = WhereFields[Idx];
for(std::vector<TERMS *>::iterator witer = whereVector.begin(); witer != whereVector.end(); ++witer)
```

And this:

```
std::vector<TERMS *>& whereVector = WhereFields[Idx];
for(auto& termsPtr : whereVector)
```

The same vector iterators incompatible error is generated in each case.  Ignoring the strange mixture of C style allocated buffers and vectors.  What is causing the error in debug mode?  Also this code appears to execute correctly in release mode, I would really like to be able to step through it in the debugger.

Thanks

Edit in response to comments:
The WhereFields[Idx] is a valid vector prior to the for loop.

A complete example of code the produces this error is:

```
int SqlHandler::VerifyColumnsInFilters (std::vector<TERMS *>*WhereFields, 
                                     const int Idx, 
                                     std::vector<TABLES *>*Tables)
{
    int Status = 0; 

    std::vector<TERMS *>& whereVector = WhereFields[Idx];
    for(auto& termsPtr : whereVector)
    {
        for(std::vector<Term *>::iterator iter = termsPtr->T.begin();
            iter != termsPtr->T.end(); ++iter)
        {
            if((*iter)->sub_q >= 0)
            {
                continue;
            }           
        }
    }
```

Nothing in the loop appears to change the actual vector in any way.

The entire error message is:  vector iterators incompatible
that is generated from this code in c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\vector

```
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    void _Compat(const _Myiter& _Right) const
        {   // test for compatible iterator pair
        if (this->_Getcont() == 0
            || this->_Getcont() != _Right._Getcont())
            {   // report error
            _DEBUG_ERROR("vector iterators incompatible");
            _SCL_SECURE_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure `WhereFields[Idx]` is a valid vector? Can you produce a [complete test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Are you changing the vector in the loop (appending things to it or removing them)?

Comment: @grayDad Instead of bla..bla..bla.. simply show the complete error message.

Comment: WhereFields[Idx] is a valid vector.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - I simply showed the complete error message along with an explanation of the context of my problem.  If you have an answer I'd appreciate it, otherwise...

Comment: When you stop at the debugging error, is the problem that `this->_Getcont()` returns null, or that it returns something different than `_Right._Getcont()`? And does it definitely happen in the whereVector iterator comparison, and not maybe in the termsPtr iterator comparison? One wonderful way to spend a lot of time debugging without finding anything is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @Sebastian - It appears that this->_Getcont() is returning 0.  Its definitely in the whereVector iterator comparison.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that `WhereFields[Idx]` is a valid vector (and you should triple-check this!), then this could indicate, for example, a mismatch between modules (DLLs). Maybe the module that created the vector is not using the debug STL, while the module that consumes the vector is.

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that `Idx` is not pointing to a valid member of the array of vectors pointed to by `WhereFields` (the most likely guess is that the vector has been destroyed but references to it yet remain - it may still *appear* valid but is in fact dead). You should check the calling point for the value of `Idx` AND confirm that vectors have been properly constructed within the `WhereFields` array.

Comment: Idx is 0.  If I change the code to a for loop like for(size_t i=0;i<whereVector.size();i++) there is no error and everything executes correctly.

Comment: @grayDad Are you using `operator[]` or `at()` with the index?

Comment: Inside the loop using the size_t I index into the whereVector using the operator[], like  TERMS * termsPtr = whereVector[i];  This works with no errors.